# Html dom add class to all elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to addclass to all elements at once using html dom. // No jquery

Here is what i tryed:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("*").classList.add('addedclassname');
```

I guess i could not select(get) all elements. Because this,

```
document.getElementById("id").classList.add('addedclassname');
```

was working.

Comment: `document.getElementByTagName("*")` returns collection of elements but `classList` is a property of single `Element`... You are suppose to loop through all the elements.. I feel `getElementsById` mentions in OP is typo..

Comment: `[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("*"),function(el){
el.classList.add('addedclassname');
});` should work...

Comment: How can i do this at once?

Comment: You have a collection, to attach property to each element, you will have to loop them...

Comment: As suggested above, you will have to loop through the node list/collection but I would also recommend you use `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].getElementsByTagName('*');` otherwise you will be adding a `class` to all tags `<script>` `<head>` `<meta>`....

Answer (score 2):

You just need to iterate each element like this

```
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(var i = 0, all = els.length; i < all; i++){   
         els[i].classList.add('addedclassname');
     }
```

Comment: So there is no way to do this without loop?

Comment: I dont think... beceause getElementsByTagName return HTMLCollection Object who contains each tag. So you must loop each element to apply the class.

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate them;

```
var elementList = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for(var i = 0; i < elementList.length; i++)
{
    elementList[i].classList.add('addedclassname');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function addClass(){
document.getElementsByTagName("*")[0].setAttribute("class", "demo")
}
```

```css
.demo {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>this is h1 element</h1>
<p>hello this is p element</p>
<h2>this is h2 element</h2>
<button onclick='addClass()'>add class</button>
```